# How do I get the full text to show in Unity 3D UI?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the full text to display when entering play mode but its only showing the first few words.

I already set the Horizontal and Vertical overflow to wrap and truncate.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of Unity game]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show all the text the rect transform should be big enough to contain all the text when using (Wrap, Truncate) settings.

Prese **"T"** while the text object is selected to see the size of the transform, you can also see in inspector, it is 160w,30h. Which is way too small for a large text. Increase it about 300w,300h and then set paragraph overflow mode horizontal: Wrap, vertical: Overflow. Setting vertical to overflow might result in text going out of the panel but it would give you an idea how tall your panel should be to display all the text in boundary.

You can also use best fit option to size down the text to fit inside the transform boundary.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was simple. This really helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have given your font size as 24. But it seems there's a lot of text to show. I would suggest make the text box bigger. Then select the **Best Fit** option in the inspector.